# Properly Loop Array Items in Comma Separated Format

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am running an ExpressJS application with EJS as my templating engine and I am running into an issue where I want to display the items in my array in a comma separated format like so, `test, list, chair`, but currently I display all of my items in a vertical list. What is the best way to do this?

Here is my loop:

```
                <p>Tags:
                <% for(var i=0; i<blogpost.tags.length; i++) { %>
                <a href="/tag/<%= blogpost.tags[i] %>"><%= blogpost.tags[i] %></a></p>
                <% } %>
```

Comment: I don't know EJS, but if you can call normal JS, I would just do `blogpost.tags.join(', ')`.

Comment: Try replacing `</p>` by a comma and move `</p>` out of the loop.